# Sequence of dependency injection in ASP.Net Core Pipeline changes after user logs in

Tags: asp.net-core, identity, multi-tenant

TLDR: Before login, the custom `UserManager` and `RoleManager` are constructed AFTER the tenant resolution middleware kicks in (which is what I expect), but once a user is logged in (authenticated), the `UserManager` and `RoleManager` are constructed BEFORE the tenant resolution middleware kicks in, so my question is, *why does this sequence change, and is there anything I can do to prevent it*?.

I have the following pipeline configured in my ASP.Net Core 3.1 application (I need `UseAuthentication` before `UseMultiTenancy` because the tenant is resolved from a claim on the logged in user principal.):

```
...;
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseMultitenancy<Tenant>();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    ...
});
```

Authentication is configured in the `ConfigureServices` method as follows (note that I have a custom UserManager and RoleManager):

```
services.AddIdentity<TenantUser, TenantRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CoreDataContext>()
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddUserManager<MyApplicationUserManager<TenantUser>>()
    .AddRoleManager<MyApplicationRoleManager<TenantRole>>()
    .AddSignInManager<MyApplicationTenantSignInManager<TenantUser>>()
    .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyApplicationTenantClaimsFactory>();
services.AddScoped<MyApplicationTenantSignInManager<TenantUser>, MyApplicationTenantSignInManager<TenantUser>>();
```

The TenantResolutionMiddleware is configured to return a Default tenant for unauthenticated requests ( because again, the actual tenant is derived from a claim on the logged-in user principal.)

I have the following logger layout (note how it is configured to output the logged-in identity): 
 `layout="${longdate}|${logger}|${message}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|user: ${aspnet-user-identity}"`

The constructor of the `UserManager` and `RoleManager` have `IHttpContext` injected, so that I can get the Tenant from the `HttpContext`. It is injected and logged as follows:

```
.ctor( ..., IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) 
  : base(...)
{
  _tenant = httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext.GetTenant<Tenant>();
  logger.LogDebug($"Tenant is {_tenant?.BusinessName}");
}
```

When I run the app, I get the following log output, with my (hopefully) clarifying comments inserted:

`GET /Index` before user logs in (note how Tenant is resolved to the Default Tenant BEFORE UserManager and RoleManager are instantiated):

```
|TenantResolutionMiddleware|Resolving TenantContext using TenantResolver. |url: /|user:
|TenantResolver|Returning TenantContext<Default> |url: /|user:
|TenantResolutionMiddleware|TenantContext Resolved. Adding to HttpContext. |url: /|user:
|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager|Tenant is Default |url: /|user:
|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager|Tenant is Default |url: /|user:
```

`GET /Login' navigate to Login page.  Same sequence as above.

```
|TenantResolutionMiddleware|Resolving TenantContext using TenantResolver. |url: /Identity/Account/Login|user:
|TenantResolver|Returning TenantContext<Default> |url: /Identity/Account/Login|user:
|TenantResolutionMiddleware|TenantContext Resolved. Adding to HttpContext. |url: /Identity/Account/Login|user:
|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager|Tenant is Default |url: /Identity/Account/Login|user:
|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager|Tenant is Default |url: /Identity/Account/Login|user:
```

`POST /Login` User logs in.  Still same log sequence as above .

```
|TenantResolutionMiddleware|Resolving TenantContext using TenantResolver. |url: /Identity/Account/Login|user:
|TenantResolver|Returning TenantContext<Default> |url: /Identity/Account/Login|user:
|TenantResolutionMiddleware|TenantContext Resolved. Adding to HttpContext. |url: /Identity/Account/Login|user:
|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager|Tenant is Default |url: /Identity/Account/Login|user:
|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager|Tenant is Default |url: /Identity/Account/Login|user:
|FlowBridge.MVC.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel|User logged in. |url: /Identity/Account/Login|user:
```

The login is successful, and the (now-authenticated) user is redirected back to the home page.  Now note the change in the logging sequence...now `UserManager` and `RoleManager` are instantiated BEFORE TenantResolution middleware.  * Why this change ??*

```
|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager|Tenant is  |url: /|user:
|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager|Tenant is  |url: /|user:
|TenantResolutionMiddleware|Resolving TenantContext using TenantResolver. |url: /|user: testuser@email.com
|TenantResolver|Returning TenantContext<Bio Sculpture Western Cape> |url: /|user: testuser@email.com
|TenantResolutionMiddleware|TenantContext Resolved. Adding to HttpContext. |url: /|user: testuser@email.com
```

And so it happens for every other request.  This causes problems for me because the UserManager and RoleManager now don't know who the Tenant is.  Why does the sequence of construction of these dependencies change?

Comment: `app.UseMultitenancy<Tenant>()` Can you share more information about Multitenancy middleware?

Comment: It makes use of `Saaskit` (https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit), which effectively resolves the tenant, and then stores it as an object in the `HttpContext's` `Items` collection.